# Is my understanding about the number of iterations correct?

Tags: terminology

Per [google machine-learning glossary](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/glossary#iteration), when I have 100 training examples and update my model for each training example, if I train my model 5 epochs without early-stop, there are 500 iterations in total, is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating model for each training example means batch size of 1, aka stochastic gradient descent(SGD).

1 iteration is defined as forward propagate, calculate loss, backpropagate and finally update weights.

Since batch size is 1, running 5 epochs on 100 training examples with SGD means you will do 500 iterations, yes.